# Polyfill for javascript template strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings

Are there any polyfills for javascript template strings that use a backtick? I'm referring to code that looks like this:

```
var textTemplate = `
   <h1>My Template String</h1>
   <p>Some more stuf here...</p>
`;
```

I do not wish to use a transpiler such as babel or any other tools that require a build step. Additionally, javascript template engines that place the template inside of a separate script tag are not ideal for me either.

I'd really just like to be able to use template strings alongside otherwise standard ES5 code in the same file. Is this possible?

EDIT: I specifically need template strings to work in IE11. I realize they already do in most other browsers. I'm also now aware that polyfill isn't the correct terminology for what I am wanting.

Comment: Polyfills are for functions and objects and such, not for syntax. Template strings are syntax. You need a transpiler.

Comment: Sorry, the concept of polyfills and shims are fairly new to me. I'm still learning so my terminology is a bit off there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Are there any polyfills for javascript template strings that use a backtick?

No.  You can't have a polyfill for new Javascript syntax which the backticks are.  A polyfill can't affect the compiling of the code or the execution of a line of code.  It can only affect functions calls at run time.

The solution for new Javascript syntax is to transpile from the new syntax to ES5 compatible code.

You can't even create a function that would do the same type of string substitution (when passed a normal Javascript quoted string) because the function implementation would not have access to the locally scoped variables that are typically used in backtick templates.

There are other types of string substitution that can be implemented in a function, but you have to pass the values that you want substituted in (like sprintf in C and use a different syntax than the template literals) rather than just use variable names in the template string.

Comment: Thank you. This is really what I was afraid of, but I wanted to make sure before I jump back into transpilers again. For this particular project I just wanted a dead simple way to build html templates in JS without any extra libraries or tools. Wishful thinking I guess.

Comment: @UglyBoogaloo - There are plenty of HTML template libraries that work with ES5 just fine.  No need to invent your own if you want to use one, but yes you would need to bring in an external library.